# Adding an integer and a tuple as column members of every row of a 2D vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, integer, tuples, 2d

I am trying to create a 2 D vector like this:

```
{{200, (44,66)},
 {242, (13,44)},
 {300, (23,71)}}
```

I tried a syntax like this :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(100, std::vector<int>(5));
typedef std::tuple<int, int>node_keys;
matrix[0][0] = 200;
matrix[0][1] = node_keys(44,66);
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Assigning to 'std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::value_type' (aka 'int') from incompatible type 'node_keys' (aka 'tuple<int, int>')
```

Now I don't know what should I do. I tried looking everywhere for some idea but couldn't find one. I believe this is something to do with compatibility issues between trying to group two different data-types inside a vector ?! Please enlighten me.

Comment: Do you want to [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) `200` to `(44,66)` ?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a N x 2 matrix. My first column is all integers and second column is all tuples. Every integer in the first column has its corresponding counterpart which resides in the second column of the same row.

Answer (score 1):

If every element contains two another elements you could use `std::pair`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::tuple<int, int>>> v = {
    { 200, {44,66} },
    { 242, {13,44} },
    { 300, {23,7} }
};
```